# Magento 2 - Create product and assign to category via API using category string

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

Is there a best practice for creating a product via the API and assigning it to a category with the full category string?  I can only find methods using known `category_id`

I'd like to use a process similar to a CSV import where I can pass the full path in the API call:
`Default Category/Shop by Department/Slide-Outs/Through-Frame & Above-Floor/Gear Packs & Hardware`

Instead of an ID like `127`

This way it will link the product to a category if it exists, or create one if it doesn't the way an import CSV operates.